# How to save an XmlDocument to a .csproj "formatted like Visual Studio" where empty elements are saved on separate lines?

Tags: .net, xml, powershell, formatting, visual-studio-project

Currently I've created a PowerShell script to go through hundreds (yes, hundreds) of Visual Studio projects and update the References for consistency which fixes a number of subtle bugs. This works for being able to *round-trip* 99% of the XML, such that subsequent editing project files in Visual Studio does not introduce another change.

However, with `XmlDocument.Save()`, *EMPTY elements are saved as a pair on the same line*..

```
<StartupObject></StartupObject>
```

..instead of the way the Visual Studio project editor *saves the EMPTY element split between two lines*..

```
<StartupObject>
</StartupObject>
```

This leads to needless noise on the initial commit that will be reset as programmers update the projects from within Visual Studio.

**How can a [modified] `XmlDocument` be saved using the same formatting rules Visual Studio [at least as of 2017] uses?**

Currently the save is done using an explicit `XmlWriter` and `XmlWriterSettings` using the following configuration:

```
$writerSettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$writerSettings.Indent = $true
$writerSettings.IndentChars = $indent # value stolen previously

$writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($path, $writerSettings)
$xml.Save($writer)
```

If using the the `XmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace` setting, unmodified nodes are not affected. However, in this case "improperly formatted" entries are not fixed and new nodes do not have correct indenting/formatting applied.

Preferably this can be handled with a simple modification to saving and/or settings instead of a custom writer (being the script is in PowerShell) or some post-save text manipulation (as such feels a bit of a kluge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although in general I think you should not tamper XML using regex, I also could not find any setting in the XmlWriter class that will change the style in which empty elements are written.

The only way I got it formatted the way you want is by having the XmlWriter write to a memory stream and use regex `-replace` on that:

```
$writerSettings             = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$writerSettings.Indent      = $true
$writerSettings.IndentChars = '  '
$writerSettings.Encoding    = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $false  # set to UTF-8 No BOM

# create a stream object to write to
$stream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream

$writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($stream, $writerSettings)
$writer.WriteStartDocument()
$writer.WriteStartElement("Root")
$writer.WriteElementString("StartupObject", [string]::Empty)
$writer.WriteElementString("AnotherEmptyElement", [string]::Empty)
$writer.WriteEndElement()
$writer.WriteEndDocument()
$writer.Flush()
$writer.Dispose()

# get whatever is written to the stream in a string variable
$xml = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString(($stream.ToArray()))

# replace self-closing elements: <StartupObject />
# replace empty elements in one line: <StartupObject></StartupObject>
# to the format where opening and closing tags are on separate lines
$format = '$1<$2>{0}$1</$2>' -f [Environment]::NewLine
$xml = $xml -replace '(.*?)<(.*?)\s*/>', $format -replace '(.*?)<(.*?)></(.*?)>', $format

# save do disk
$xml | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\test.xml' -Force -Encoding default
```

Result:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <Root>
>   <StartupObject>
>   </StartupObject>
>   <AnotherEmptyElement>
>   </AnotherEmptyElement>
> </Root>
> ```

Comment: Cool - this is what I ended up doing, wrote a blind-implementation and we ended up with almost an identical pattern. Would be some deviations in more complex cases.. Good Enough for this problem.

Comment: @user2864740 do you perhaps have that script laying around still? i'm also looking to bulk edit a bunch of files and keeping the xml file consistent means let GIT changes.

Comment: It’s all included above. It could be turned into a cmdlet with parameters and such.